# Looping through rows of a dataframe and check for duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
signal = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            [0, 0, 0],
            [-1, -1, -1],
            [1, 0, -1],
            [0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1],
            [0, -1, 1],
            [-1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0]],columns=['A','B','C'])
```

signal:

```
     A   B   C
0    0   0   0
1   -1  -1  -1
2    1   0  -1
3    0   0   0
4    1   0   0
5    0   1   0
6    0   0   1
7    0  -1   1
8   -1   0   0
9    0   0   0
```

my objective is to loop through the signal dataframe three indexes at a time and check if duplicates exist, if they do,make the latter equal to zero

For example in the signal dataframe if the index is  at A[2], I will check  for the values A[2], A[3] and A[4]. Notice that both A[2] and A[4] have the value of 1, i will change A[4] to 0

the Filtered signal dataframe below is how I expect the results to be

Filtered signal

```
    A   B   C
0   0   0   0
1  -1  -1  -1
2   1   0   0
3   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
5   0   1   0
6   0   0   1
7   0  -1   0
8  -1   0   0
9   0   0   0
```

Comment: So, if you have 4 sequential 1's in a column, only the first one remains 1?

Comment: if in A there is 1,1,1,1 you would like it to be 1,0,0,0 or 1,0,0,1?

Comment: @Wen I will like it to be 1,0,0,1

Answer (score 0):

If we create a list of the first column:

```
l = df['A']
#we copy the list just to compare it later for confirmation.
m = l.copy()
#iterate through the list and assign 0 if duplicates.
for i in range(0, len(m), 3):
    if m[i + 1] == m[i]:
        m[i+ 1] = 0
    if m[i + 2] == m[i]:
        m[i + 2] = 0
#re-assign the list to the column
df['A'] = m
```